# Which one I should download? "Download the latest version of libclang"

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, youcompleteme

I want to install YouCompleteMe, on Mac OSX, early 2015.

I have installed it under guidance of [Mac OSX part](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#mac-os-x). However, I got one warning:

```
NoExtraConfDetected: No .ycm_extra_conf.py file detected.
```

Then I read the [full installation guide](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#full-installation-guide), and know that I should **Download the latest version of libclang**. However, there are so many source code on [the official webpage of LLVM](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html), and I don't know what to install (figure below).

So, could you please tell me, **which one I should install**?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.8.0 you can see Pre-Build binaries for MacOsX that's what you need to download and extract. Once you extract this. You will need to source it's location using the path variable.

Now, You can also install clang using brew from the terminal.

```
brew install --with-clang llvm
```

Comment: Good point... I was just wondering why there is no Mac OSX version in Download LLVM 3.8.1, then as you said, there is one in Download LLVM 3.8.0. = =                  Thanks a lot~

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --with-clang`

Comment: What happens if you try installing without `--with-clang` or maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472379, sorry I don't have a mac now so I am shooting in the dark.