# How to install llvm 5.0.0 for Mac using brew

Tags: macos, llvm, homebrew

We used below to install llvm 3.9:

```
brew install --force-bottle llvm@3.9
```

This also installed clang at following location:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm\@3.9/bin/clang
```

What would be the command to install llvm 5.0 and the corresponding location for clang?

Comment: `brew install --force-bottle llvm@5` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[updated]** On September 24, 2019, the `llvm@5` formula [was removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/0a31b157055f8bd51294438d2d84fd06de0e0cb5) due to low usage.

You can still find the [original code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/2c9d4ec833a4f4087e0a590c505b89b1b43e1d98/Formula/llvm%405.rb) in the git history. You can download it and install it:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/2c9d4ec833a4f4087e0a590c505b89b1b43e1d98/Formula/llvm%405.rb > llvm@5.rb
brew install ./llvm@5.rb
```

---

Original answer:

```
$ brew search llvm
==> Searching local taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
llvm
llvm@3.7
llvm@3.9
llvm@4
llvm@5   <------
```

You can use `brew install llvm@5` (add `--force` if needed). `clang` will be in the same location except that `3.9` is replaced with `5`:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm@5/bin/clang
```

Comment: LLVM 5 is not on GitHub anymore: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/llvm What should I do to install version 5?